# Go Template : Use nested struct's field and {{range}} tag together

Tags: go, go-html-template

I have the following nested struct and I would like to  iterate them in a template, in a `{{range .Foos}}` tag.

```
type Foo struct {
    Field1, Field2 string
}

type NestedStruct struct {
    NestedStructID string
    Foos []Foo
}
```

I'm trying with the following html/template but it can't access the `NestedStructID` from `NestedStruct`.

```
{{range .Foos}} { source: '{{.Field1}}', target: '{{.NestedStructID}}' }{{end}}
```

Is there any way with golang templates to do what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reach the `NestedStructID` field like that because the `{{range}}` action sets the pipeline (the dot `.`) in each iteration to the current element.

You may use the `$` which is set to the data argument passed to `Template.Execute()`; so if you pass a value of `NestedStruct`, you can use `$.NestedStructID`.

For example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(x))

    ns := NestedStruct{
        NestedStructID: "nsid",
        Foos: []Foo{
            {"f1-1", "f2-1"},
            {"f1-2", "f2-2"},
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, ns))
}

const x = `{{range .Foos}}{ source: '{{.Field1}}', target: '{{$.NestedStructID}}' }
{{end}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BKdxyrQVrH)):

```
{ source: 'f1-1', target: 'nsid' }
{ source: 'f1-2', target: 'nsid' }
<nil>
```

This is documented in [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Comment: Once again, thanks for this clear explanation ! It works for me :)